# Javascript match() string letters which are indicated on regular expression of match

Tags: javascript, string, function, match

I have a variable which contain a string and I want to return only the letters from regular expression (“b” **and** “D”) or any letter that I indicate on regular expression from match().

```
var kk = "AaBbCcDd".match(/b|D/g); 
     kk.forEach(function(value,index){
     console.log(value,index) 
});
```

My problem is that regular expression I think because is returning b and D but the index is not the index from `kk` variable and I'm not really sure, why ... so if someone can help me a little bit because I stuck

Comment: `"AaBbCcDd".match(/b|D/g);` will return `["b", "D"]` so the indexes will be **0** and **1** what are you expecting ?

Comment: *but the index is not the index from kk variable* - what does it mean?

Comment: @oliv37 the indexes of initial array kk

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it means in kk variable the indexes are: A-0,a-1,B-2,b-3,C-4,c-5,D-6,d-7

Comment: `var str = "AaBbCcDd";`  `kk.forEach(function(value,index){
     console.log(value,str.indexOf(value)); 
});`

Comment: @oliv37 actually this return error :|

Answer (score 1):

The `match` method from javascript only returns an array with the given match:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

You would need to implement a new function which will loop through all characters of your string and return the given index of the matches.
This method could use the function `search` from String.prototype: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a new function to get the index of the matched regex like a sample below:-

```
var re = /bar/g,
  str = "foobarfoobar";
while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) {
  alert("match found at " + match.index);
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: in your function will always return the position of "bar" but if you want to return the position of "bar" and the position of "foo" how will you do this ? because that is the scenario that I need.

Comment: Just try adding your regex expression and it should return indexes for both the matches...

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is the answer :

```
var kk = "AaBbCcDd".match(/B?d?/g); 
     kk.forEach(function(value,index){
     console.log(value,index) 
});
```

if someone will encounter this scenario ...

The `match()` regular expresion `B?d?` will return an array indicating the position of `"B"` and `"d"` of the initial array kk.